# Debugging kernel modules on kernel version 3.5.0 using vmware

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

The specs are not my choice, the class I'm in requires it. I do have root access to the machine though. Our last project ended poorly due to us having zero ability to debug it, crashes were virtually impossible to trace.

I tried using IDA by binding to a remote gdb session but it crashes every time I begin to log in (followed this guide and tried multiple times https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/debugging_gdb_linux_vmware.pdf)

So far I'm out of ideas and Google hasn't gotten me anything useful. Any ideas on how I can debug crashes?

Comment: What exactly crashed? The kernel got an oops or panic? Please be more specific, you are more likely to get help this way. If you are trying to debug a kernel problem, please provide the relevant info: kernel version and flavour, distro name, logs, etc. Or the problem is that you cannot retrieve the needed info from that machine? It is unclear.

Comment: Also, if you are allowed to share the source code of the module you suspect to be faulty, please post it here. It will be easier for the experts out there to see what may go wrong in it.

Comment: I'm not looking for specific help on a kernel module, that assignment was due a long time ago. I am looking for general help on how to debug kernel modules on that version of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more utility to debug where your code goes into crash condition using **valgrind** which helps to debug code much more compare to gdb.